# ASP.NET Back Button for multiple forms

Tags: asp.net, navigation

I am trying to track navigation between a number of Web Forms in ASP.NET.  I've tried the client side back navigation using the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="BackButton" runat="server" Text="Back" 
            OnClientClick="JavaScript:window.history.back(1);return false;" />
```

Unfortunately this does not work for my scenario due to postbacks going on.  My scenario has a number of Web Forms:

- Page1.1
- Page1.2
- Page2
- Page3

Navigating forward through the pages works similarly to a wizard.  There are 2 starting points - from Page1.1 and Page1.2.

Page1.1 -> Page2 -> Page3
Page1.2 -> Page2 -> Page3

So clicking back buttons will have the following navigation:

Page3 -> Page2
Page2 -> Page1.1
Page2 -> Page1.2

There are additional parameters passed between the pages which need to be maintained.

I am currently looking at maintaining something in the Session to maintain the current call stack which somewhat works however, I am getting a build up of referrer urls.  At the minute I am just trying to conceptualise this.

I am running this in SharePoint as Application Pages, however each page is essentially an ASP.NET page for the sake of this example.

So I have introduced an abstract class for each Page:

```
public abstract class SecureLayoutsPageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private PageController _pageController;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        _pageController = (PageController)Session["PageController"];
        if (_pageController == null)
        {
            _pageController = new PageController();
            Session["PageController"] = _pageController;
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack && Page.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
            this.PageController.History.Push(Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected PageController PageController
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageController;
        }
    }

}
```

Which has an instance of PageController:

```
[Serializable()]
public class PageController
{
    private Stack<string> _history = new Stack<string>();

    public void Previous(HttpResponse response)
    {
        string previous = _history.Pop();
        response.Redirect(previous);
    }

    public Stack<string> History
    {
        get
        {
            return _history;
        }
    }
}
```

Then each page will call the PageController.Previous in the server side event handler for the back button click:

```
protected void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PageController.Previous(this.Response);
}
```

This issue with this is that calling PageController.Previous still results in the Url being added to the stack.  I am just wondering if there is a way to prevent the url getting added when back has been clicked.  Or alternative solutions...

Answer (score 0):

History(-1) wont work, because this will include postbacks. Just set the button href dependant on whatever page you're on. If you know itsloaded page 3, set the back button to page 2

Comment: Yep that's kind of straight forward, but then you get back to page 2, and you click back on Page 2, how do you know where to go back to?  Page1.1 or Page1.2!

Answer (score 0):

OK...  couple of tweaks to get my scenario working.  Not keen on this solution so any others would be good.

Change to SecureLayoutsPageBase:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    _pageController = (PageController)Session["PageController"];
    if (_pageController == null)
    {
        _pageController = new PageController();
        Session["PageController"] = _pageController;
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack && Page.Request.UrlReferrer != null && Page.Request.Url.ToString() != this.PageController.PreviousUrl)
    {
        this.PageController.AddHistory(Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Change to PageController:

```
[Serializable()]
public class PageController
{
    private Stack<string> _history = new Stack<string>();
    private string _previous;

    public void Previous(HttpResponse response)
    {
        _previous = _history.Pop();
        response.Redirect(_previous);
    }

    public void AddHistory(string url)
    {
        if(url != _previous)
        {
            _history.Push(url);
        }
    }

    public Stack<string> History
    {
        get
        {
            return _history;
        }
    }

    public string PreviousUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _previous;
        }
    }
}
```